# Why is currency and not other units included in NumberFormatInfo

Tags: c#, .net, units-of-measurement

The [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class includes several properties related to currency, e.g. CurrencySymbol. This means that one can easily format and display objects as currency using standard format strings. Parsing is also supported.

My question is, why is currency supported out of the box and not other units of measure? I would like to do the same thing with length, mass, time etc.

Would it be easy to add this functionality myself? Some structures/classes would be required of course, as one would need to know what the current unit of measure for that object is.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762932(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I've made some tests using this, but I don't think I can make a nice solution based on this. To convert a number and a unit to a string is ok, both pieces of information is there, but to parse user input and get the number and unit as Microsoft does is hard I think because of the lack of unit information from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It is just my opinion, but I think the reason why developers of .NET decided to do it in exactly way you mentioned is because of currency's huge range of variations. What I mean : no matter you are developer in US or in Russia or in China, there is the international standards for length, square, etc. measurement (**International System of Units**). Also it is the same about coordinate system, see the class Point, X.Y.(Z) is everywhere. However, it is not true about the currency. In USA official currency is dollar, in my country (Kazakhstan) it is "tenge".

Comment: I agree that the SI unit system is the way to go internally in programs, but unfortunately, not everyone would like to have their units displayed like that in the UI. One bottle of milk: 0.001m³ instead of 1L (or even 0.264 us gallons). It's the presentation to the user that causes "problems", internally I would use SI for sure.

Comment: @Henning it's also far more fragmented. I.e. what unit of length is used in the UK? It depends on what you're measuring. We'll use meters for many things but still use Miles and Yards on our road signage.

Comment: Units of measure are standardized, immutable, and limited in number (basically, there are only two systems), so you can write your own conversion functions with confidence.

Comment: I've got a conversion library alright, but what I haven't found a good solution for is how to stick with SI internally in my program and only use a different unit system in the UI (display and input).